An order problem and an enumeration problem involved origyear in biblatex
First a minimal working sample and its output are as follows.
\documentclass{ctexart}

\usepackage[utf8, backend=biber, style=caspervector-ay,
sorting=cenyt%
]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{origdate}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\iffieldundef{origyear}
             {}
             {\undef\cbx@lastyear}%
           \ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                       \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
             {\setunit{\addcomma}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:extradate}}
             {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
              \printorigdate
              \setunit*{\addspace}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
              \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
           \printorigdate
           \setunit*{\addspace}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{citeyear}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\iffieldundef{origyear}
             {}
             {\undef\cbx@lastyear}%
           \ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                       \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
             {\setunit{\addcomma}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:extradate}}
             {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
              \printorigdate
              \setunit*{\addspace}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
              \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}
          {\printorigdate
           \setunit*{\addspace}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\iffieldundef{origyear}
          {}
          {\undef\cbx@lastyear}%
        \ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                    \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
          {\setunit{\addcomma}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:extradate}}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
           \printorigdate
           \setunit*{\addspace}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}
       {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
        \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}}
    {\ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{%
             \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
             \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
           \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
             {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
             {}%
           \printorigdate
           \setunit*{\addspace}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{%
          \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
          \printdelim{nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
        \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
          {}%
        \iffieldundef{shorthand}
          {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
             {\printorigdate
              \setunit*{\addspace}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
           \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}}%
     \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
    \textcitedelim}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printorigdate
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iflabeldateisdate
    {\printdateextra}
    {\printlabeldateextra}}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{ot2001,
  location  = {Place},
  publisher = {ABC},
  author    = {Name, Given},
  title     = {One title},
  year      = {2001},
  origyear  = {1979},
}
@book{at2001,
  location  = {Place},
  publisher = {ABC},
  author    = {Name, Given},
  title     = {Another title},
  year      = {2001},
  origyear  = {1973},
}
@book{ta1989,
  location  = {Place},
  publisher = {ABC},
  author    = {Family, Given},
  title     = {Title A},
  year      = {1989},
  origyear  = {1960},
}
@book{tb1982,
  location  = {Place},
  publisher = {ABC},
  author    = {Family, Given},
  title     = {Title B},
  year      = {1982},
  origyear  = {1960},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{ot2001,at2001}

\cite{ta1989,tb1982}

\printbibliography
\end{document}


Note that, use XeLaTeX to compile the file.
To print origyear in both the citation and the reference list, I add the codes with the help of @moewe (see here). But now, I find an order problem and an enumeration problem.

As you see, Family, Given, (1960) 1989 lists before Family, Given, (1960) 1982. While Family, Given, (1960) 1989 should list after Family, Given, (1960) 1982. It's invoking cenyt that leads to the problem since if we comment it then the problem disappears. So how to rewrite the cenyt in caspervector to solve the order problem?
As you see, in both Name, Given, (1973) 2001a and Name, Given, (1979) 2001b, there are English letters after the years. While there should be no English letters after the years if the origyears are different when authors and years are the same. So how to solve the enumeration problem?


@moewe I think you should have some ideas to the problems.

I think it would be appropriate to draft a separate answer, leaving the original intact. Naturally, I'm basing this one on the previous.
1. The order problem. (changed)
Well, to modify the sorting template, you should move the check of the origyear field. I think this is be sufficient for your needs.
\DeclareSortingTemplate{cenyt}{
    \sort{\field{presort}}
    \sort[final]{\field{sortkey}}
    \sort[direction = descending]{
        \field{userf}}
    \sort{
        \field{sortname}
        \field{author}
        \field{editor}
        \field{translator}
        \field{sorttitle}
        \field{title}}
    \sort{
        \field{origyear}
        \field{origmonth}
        \field{origday}
        \field{sortyear}
        \field{year}} 
    \sort{
        \field{sortyear}
        \field{year}}
    \sort{
        \field{sorttitle}
        \field{title}}
    \sort{
        \field{volume}
        \literal{0}}}

2. The enumeration problem.
2-0. Fixing the extradate field. (correction of a misprint)
Concerning the extradate field, to fix it to the origdate date rather than the date, maybe this is the solution.
First of all, you should add origyear to the information used to construct the extradate field.
\DeclareExtradate{%
    \scope{
        \field{origyear}
        \field{labelyear}
        \field{year}}%
    \scope{
        \field{labelyear}
        \field{year}}}

2-bis. Creation of flexible macros to suppress the printing of day, month, origday and origmonth fields. (new)
With the next new macros, configured in this manner, I provide to ensure that the extradate field is printed, when required, within the year field.
\newbibmacro{citing:origdate}{%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}%
        {}%
        {\printtext[parens]{%
        \printfield{origyear}}}}%
            
\newbibmacro{citing:date}{%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{year}%
    \printfield{extradate}}}%

In general, I replaced some commands (such as the \prinorigdateextra one) with the same macros in the following steps.
I also created the next macro, which combines the previous ones.
\newbibmacro*{citing:date+extradate}{%
    \printtext{\usebibmacro{citing:origdate}}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printtext{\usebibmacro{citing:date}}}

2-ter. Continuing from the corresponding section in the previous response. (changed)
Then, try to customise the date+extradate macro.
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
    \usebibmacro{citing:origdate}%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}%
        {\setunit*{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
        {\setunit*{\addspace}}%
    \printtext[bold]{\usebibmacro{citing:date}}}

2-quater. Customisation of nameyeardelim (new)
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}%
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}%
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}%

3. The new cite and textcite macros. (changed)
Here there are the new cite and textcite macros.
First of all, the new cite one.
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}%
        \printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit*{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{citing:date+extradate}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
        {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
            {\iffieldundef{origyear}%
                {}%
                {\undef\cbx@lastyear}%
            \ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                   \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
                {\setunit{\addcomma}%
                \iffieldundef{origyear}%
                    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{extradate}}}%
                    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{date}}}}%
                {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
                \usebibmacro{citing:date+extradate}%
                \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}%
            {\printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
            \usebibmacro{citing:date+extradate}%
            \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
            \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
\setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother

Subsequently, I customised this macro, which is recurring in the parent textcite one.
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}%
        {}%
        {\printfield[parens]{origyear}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printlabeldateextra}}}

Finally, here you are the new textcite macro. Perhaps, the change isn't very obvious at first glance. I added the \iffieldundef{origyear} condition and repeated the application of the cite:labeldate+extradate macro whenever the origyear field exists.
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
    \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
    \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}%
    {\setunit{\addcomma}%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:extradate}}%
        {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}%
    {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
    \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}%
    {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
    \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}}%
    {\ifnameundef{labelname}%
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
    \setunit{%
    \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
    \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
    \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}%
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}%
    {\printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{%
    \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
    \printdelim{nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
    \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}%
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {}%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    {\iffieldundef{labelyear}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}%
    \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
    \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}}%
    \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
    \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
    \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}%
    {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}%
    {}%
    \textcitedelim}}
\makeatother

You can also see how I restored the normal (non-bold) format for the date. In the date+extradate macro, the date remains bold thanks to a specific option.
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{#1}

4. Adjustment for the \citeyear command. (new)
Finally, it is necessary a further adjustment for the \citeyear command, to associate this command also with the original year of the entry (when given).
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear}%
    {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
    \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}%
        {}%
        {\printtext[parens]{%
            \printfield{origyear}}%
            \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \printfield[bibhyperref]{year}}%
    {\multicitedelim}%
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

This customisation is suitable, if you would have to mention also the origyear field by default and to make an exception the mention everytime of only the (current) yera. The exceptional command may be the next one.
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearnoextra}%
    {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
    \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printfield[bibhyperref]{year}}%
    {\multicitedelim}%
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

4-bis. Double round parens in \textcite citations. (after the comment)
To force double roundparens, namely to have a citation command which always yse round parens even in case of nested parens, first of all create a specific format.
\DeclareFieldFormat{roundparens}{(#1)}

Then, apply it instead of parens wherever you prefere. For example, modifyig the cite:labeldate+extradate macro again to print \printfield[roundparens]{origyear} instead of \printfield[roundparens]{origyear} will disenable the switch to brackets.
This format is suitable especially for the \textcite citation command, which use to nest parens, according to this style and to the necessity of printing the origyear field if given.
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}%
        {}%
        {\printfield[roundparens]{origyear}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printlabeldateextra}}}

Just note that for the \citeyear citing command (that we customised to print by default also the origyear field if given) it wouldn't be necessary to specify the roundparens format instead of the parens one for the origyear field. I mean: if you use the \citeyear citing command in the text within round parens, LaTeX doesn't see a nest and so you don't have to force the double round parens.
Authorship Statement. The present version of the answer is collaboratively developed with significant input from the initial inquirer, the user M. Logic.

In that case, delete both the citeyear macro and the \citeyear citation command, as modified by me, to restore to their original meaning and let them referred only to the year field. Subsequently, create a new citation command \citeyearandorig. \DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearandorig}{\usebibmacro{prenote}}{\usebibmacro{citeindex}\iffieldundef{origyear}{}{\printtext[parens]{\printfield{origyear}}\setunit{\addspace}}\printfield{year}}{\multicitedelim}{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

Try with the changes added with the supplementary sections 4-bis and 4-ter, just published at the bottom of this answer.

1. The order problem
Well, to modify the sorting template, you should move the check of the origyear field. I think this is be sufficient for your needs.
\DeclareSortingTemplate{cenyt}{
    \sort{\field{presort}}
    \sort[final]{\field{sortkey}}
    \sort[direction = descending]{
        \field{userf}}
    \sort{
        \field{sortname}
        \field{author}
        \field{editor}
        \field{translator}
        \field{sorttitle}
        \field{title}}
    \sort{
        \field{origyear}
        \field{origmonth}
        \field{origday}}
    \sort{
        \field{sortyear}
        \field{year}}
    \sort{
        \field{sorttitle}
        \field{title}}
    \sort{
        \field{volume}
        \literal{0}}}

2. The enumeration problem
Concerning the extradate field, to fix it to the origdate rather than the date, maybe this is the solution.
First of all, you should add origdate to the information used to construct the extradate field.
\DeclareExtradate{%
    \scope{\field{origyear}
    \field{labelyear}
    \field{year}}}

Then, try to customise the date+extradate macro.
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printorigdateextra%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printtext[bold]{\iffieldundef{origyear}%
        {\iflabeldateisdate%
            {\printdateextra}
            {\printlabeldateextra}}%
        {\iflabeldateisdate%
            {\printdate}
            {\printlabeldate}}}}

I replaced the \printorigdate command with the \printorigdateextra one. Then, I made the \printdateextra and \printlabeldataextra commands contingent upon the origyear field being undefined.
I hope that all of this works and satisfies your needs.
Update
I forgot to include the new macros cite and textcite. Here they are.
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}%
        \printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext{\printorigdateextra}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \iffieldundef{origyear}%
            {\iflabeldateisdate%
                {\printlabeldateextra}%
                {\printdate}}%
            {\printdate}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
        {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
            {\iffieldundef{origyear}%
                {}%
                {\undef\cbx@lastyear}%
            \ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                   \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
                {\setunit{\addcomma}%
                \iffieldundef{origyear}%
                    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{extradate}}}%
                    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{date}}}}%
                {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
                \printorigdateextra%
                \setunit*{\addspace}%
                \iffieldundef{origyear}%
                    {\iflabeldateisdate%
                    {\printdateextra}%
                    {\printlabeldateextra}}%
                    {\iflabeldateisdate%
                    {\printdate}%
                    {\printlabeldate}}%
                \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}%
            {\printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
            \printorigdateextra%
            \setunit{\addspace}%
            \iffieldundef{origyear}%
                {\iflabeldateisdate%
                {\printdateextra}%
                {\printlabeldateextra}}%
                {\iflabeldateisdate%
                {\printdate}%
                {\printlabeldate}}%
            \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
            \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
\setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
{\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
{\iffieldundef{origyear}%
    {}%
    {\undef\cbx@lastyear}%
\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
\(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}%
    {\setunit{\addcomma}%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}%
        {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{extradate}}}%
        {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{date}}}}%
    {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
    \printorigdateextra%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}%
        {\iflabeldateisdate%
        {\printdateextra}%
        {\printlabeldateextra}}%
        {\iflabeldateisdate%
        {\printdate}%
        {\printlabeldate}}%
    \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}%
{\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
\global\undef\cbx@lastyear}}%
{\ifnameundef{labelname}%
{\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
    \setunit{\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
    \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
    \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}%
        {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
        {}%
    \printorigdateextra%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}%
        {\iflabeldateisdate%
        {\printdateextra}%
        {\printlabeldateextra}}%
        {\iflabeldateisdate%
        {\printdate}%
        {\printlabeldate}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}%
{\printnames{labelname}%
\setunit{\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
\printdelim{nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}%
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {}%
\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    {\iffieldundef{labelyear}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}%
        {\printorigdateextra%
        \setunit*{\addspace}%
        \iffieldundef{origyear}%
            {\iflabeldateisdate%
            {\printdateextra}%
            {\printlabeldateextra}}%
            {\iflabeldateisdate%
            {\printdate}%
            {\printlabeldate}}}%
    \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
    \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}}%
\stepcounter{textcitecount}%
\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
\setunit{\ifbool{cbx:parens}%
    {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}%
    {}%
\textcitedelim}}
\makeatother

You can also see how I restored the normal (non-bold) format for the date. In the date+extradate macro, the date remains bold thanks to a specific option.
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{#1}%


While for the enumeration problem, it brings about two further problems. One is that the two 1960s become 1960a and 1960b which are not suitable, but this could be solved with \printorigdate instead of \prinorigdateextra. Another is that when the date and origdate are long, for example, 1960-01-01 and 1989-02-03, then ... (1960) 1989 would become ... (1960-01-01) 1989-02-03. I don't know how to make ... (1960-01-01) 1989-02-03 go back to ... (1960) 1989.

I completely revised the answer. Please accept my apologies for all the second thoughts in my previous attempts. I discovered some errors in my second answer. Therefore, I can now refer you to the other answer.
